# Video make POST or GET

Tags: html, flash, video, interaction

I'm trying to create some video when sometime the people inside the video will make a call for the viewer.

So, I have one video that I need to trigger one event, a POST or GET.

What better way to do this? maybe some html5 code, I don't know the best idea.

Comment: What does this mean:`make a call for the viewer`? What exactly are you tying to do?

Comment: I'll have a video and the actor will call to viewer at especific time of the video (it's a POST action)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using HTML5 video you can use the `timeupdate` event to track the time and fire some action.

```
<div id="stage">
  <video src="http://example.com/myvideo.webm" controls id=myvideo></video> 
</div>       

<script>
  var timeOfEvent = 30; //time of event in seconds
  (function(){
    var v = document.getElementById('myvideo');

    v.addEventListener('timeupdate',function(event){
     if (v.currentTime >= timeOfEvent) {
         // perform your action here
         // You'll need to ensure your action only fires once.
     }

    },false);
  })();
</script>
```

**Note:** The `currentTime` is not an integer, and the time between the `timeupdate` events can vary, so trying to do something at an exact point in the video almost certainly won't work. You can test for the integer portion of `currentTime` (i.e. whole seconds) or for a range (e.g `currentTime > 10 || currentTime <20`), but both of these will probably occur more than once. For simple screen updates this might not matter, but for any action that should occur only once you'd need to track that somehow to prevent it being executed several times.

Comment: I don't know what it's doens't working. It just ignore the addEventListener http://prntscr.com/1b9gx1

Comment: Sorry - there's a typo in the sample here:`var v = document.getElementsById('myvideo');`. It should be `getElementById('myvideo')` (no 's'). See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qBqQe/)

Comment: Sorry for the noob questions maybe. But why it doesn't work with "==" instead of ">="  see the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/qBqQe/7/

Comment: The time index returned is not an integer, and the rate at which the timeupdate event is raised can vary. It very unlikely that the event will be raised at exactly the time you specify. You could test for an integer (intval(currentTime,10) == timeOfEvent), or for the currentTime in a range.